# Using Erlang Application Module for Globals

Tags: erlang

Are there any downsides to using the application:get_env / application:set_env to keep global state dynamically?

Example:

I have a module that handles http requests.
I have a collection of http request handlers.
I want to register/get http request handlers via the application env.

```erlang
start() ->
  % Init default handlers
  application:set_env(?REQUEST_HANDLER_MODULES, [foo_handler, bar_handler]).

add_http_request_handler(Module) ->
  % Register handler at runtime
  Modules = application:get_env(?REQUEST_HANDLER_MODULES),
  application:set_env(?REQUEST_HANDLER_MODULES, [Module|Modules]).

handle_request(Req) ->
  Modules = application:get_env(?REQUEST_HANDLER_MODULES),
  handle_request(Req, Modules, {}).

handle_request(Req, [], Agg) ->
  Agg;
handle_request(Req, [M|L], Agg) ->
  handle_request(Req, L, M:handle(Req, Agg)).
```

---

What are the downsides to this?

Does this require a round trip to an application process each time application:get_env is fetched?

Is this a functional anti-pattern?

Comment: in `add_http_request_handler`, is this line correct ? `Modules = ?REQUEST_HANDLER_MODULES,` because then you will always have the same starting point every time that function gets called.

Comment: @Agus Updated. I meant to fetch the value at ?REQUEST_HANDLER_MODULES (a key, not a value)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have persistent storage i.e. maintain the exact data after Erlang VM restart, I think you should go with Mnesia's `disc_copies` table. Based on my experience, this beast can handle load and concurrency very well.

Comment: I know. But that's not what I was asking